# Disable notarization checks for SSH sessions

Tags: macos, ssh, development, notarization

With macOS 10.15 and later, before an executable runs for the first time, macOS will query an Apple server. This can be a significant hindrance with some development tasks: I'm dealing with a test suite that runs 500+ executables, and this security feature slows this down from seconds to minutes. This issue is discussed here along with a solution:

- https://sigpipe.macromates.com/2020/macos-catalina-slow-by-design/

Add Terminal.app to the "Developer Tools" category of the Security & Privacy section of System Preferences. This works fine when using any graphical terminal app. But **how can I disable this notarization check for SSH sessions** when connecting to a macOS machine remotely?

Comment: Are your binaries notarized and is the notarization stapled? Those should yield the biggest performance increase from my experiences.

Comment: @bmike I assume not, since I am not familiar with the specifics of notarization. Think simple binaries output directly by the C compiler, `cc prog.c -o prog`. Since these are part of the test suite of a library I'm contributing to, they get recompiled often. The notarization check is re-done each time. On my personal machine I still use macOS 10.14, which is free from this problem. I now have remote access to a machine with a more recent OS, and this "feature" is making life much harder there ...

Comment: Apple has an API for notarization and the results are fast. Putting it in your build chain is easy with command line support. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution long term, this is going to become more painful for you if I’m reading the tea leaves correctly for Ventura.

Comment: This is not an end-user app written specifically for macOS. These binaries will never be distributed. The project is a cross-platform library, with nothing specific to macOS. All I'm looking for is pain-free development on a Mac, just like on any other Unix-like system. Surely there must be a way to do that?